# Calculated Column to Determine if Value Appears in Column of Any Row Filtered on Non-Unique ID

Tags: powerpivot

I have a set of data in PowerPivot that has non-unique IDs on which I group items for reporting purposes. Each row is a unique item called a task and multiple tasks may be associated with one item called a review. Each task may require action. As such, the table looks something like this (without the ReviewAction column):

```
TaskID      Action      ReviewID    ReviewAction
------------------------------------------------
1           True        1           True
2           False       1           True
3           False       2           False
4           True        3           True
5           False       4           False
6           False       4           False
7           False       5           True
8           True        5           True
9           False       5           True
```

Is there a way to produce ReviewAction as a calculated column (Display True if *any* tasks associated with a review require action)? For example, Review 1 contains Tasks 1 and 2. Task 1 requires action so ReviewAction is set to True for any row associated with Review 1. Likewise, Review 5 contains Tasks 7, 8, and 9. Only Task 8 requires action, but I want ReviewAction to display True for all rows associated with Review 5.

I have used the following function to count if Review IDs are duplicates, and if so, how many duplicates there are:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('TableName'), FILTER('TableName', [ReviewID]=EARLIER([ReviewID])))
```

I haven't been able to figure out a way to use this same filtering technique to produce the ReviewAction column, however.

The reason I'm trying to produce this column is so that I can create a chart that counts the Review items (just with a distinct count) and includes a slicer to filter by reviews that require action or not. In order to create a slicer, I need that "ReviewAction" value to exist as a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H Jimmy,

Very interesting case, I was dealing with something similar and found an elegant (not sure how performance-smart) way to do this using X-functions. In this case, [MAXX](https://support.office.com/client/MAXX-0f02ee3a-5dba-439a-bb08-cc63f09d5e49) will help:

```
=
MAXX (
    FILTER ( 'Table', [Review ID] = EARLIER ( [Review ID] ) ),
    INT ( [Action] )
)
```

It takes sub-tables grouped by *Review ID* and then calculates **maximum** for this group, using INTEGER value of True/False statements. Then, just wrap it inside an IF clause:

```
=
IF (
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', [Review ID] = EARLIER ( [Review ID] ) ),
        INT ( [Action] )
    )
        = 1,
    TRUE (),
    FALSE ()
)
```

And you will get what you need. The source Excel 2013 file can be [downloaded here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/258211/MAXX.xlsx).

Hope this helps.

[image]